# Detect when URL changes in WebView - Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

It is my first time working with Xamarin, and need to show up a back button on the screen only when the URL of my WebView is different from the first one, so that the users can go back to the "home" page of the web site. If there is any function that gets called once the page is completely loaded so I can get the URL and compare with the previos one would be great. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `url` from the event  **webView.Navigated**

```
webView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;
```

```
private void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var url = e.Url;
    //...
}
```

Comment: How can i do this in xamarin.ios instead of xamarin.form?